# how to set counter of loop inside loop correctly inside jmeter?

Tags: loops, jmeter, load-testing

I have jmeter flow like this:

```
ThreadGroup
--Sampler to get the number of items and store to vars("numItem",XYZ)
--LoopController on $numItem
-----Sampler to get number of subItem and store to vars("numSubitem", ABC)
-----LoopController on $numSubitem
-----LoopCounter
-----Sampler: print out the current counter from loopCounter
```

For example, the number of item = 2 and subItem = 10, my loopCounter print out will be 0 - 19.  I have checked the checkbout "Track counter independently for each user" but it doesn't affect because this is the same thread. Is there a way to make the counter count 0 - 9 and then 0 - 9.

Thanks,

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your example you can define additional var `maxCount = subItem - 1` and set it as value of "Maximum" field for "Counter" instance, as shown below:

In sampler where numSubitem is set (before 2nd loop):

```
int numSubitem = 10;
int maxCounter = numSubitem - 1;
vars.put("numSubitem",Integer.toString(numSubitem));
vars.put("maxCounter",Integer.toString(maxCounter));
```

I've used Beanshell Sampler for test, you can use Beanshell Postprocessor, e.g.

In Counter instance:

[image]

So counter will iterate as in your description.