# Looping in JMeter based on condition

Tags: while-loop, controller, jmeter

I have a scenario where a HTTP request needs to be executed multiple times in two loops as said below:

-Thread Group
 -While Controller
  -While Controller
   -HTTP Request
   -BeanShell Post Processor(1)
  -BeanShell Post processor(2)

HTTP Request: 
https://xx.xxx.xx.xx/api/v1/xx/utilization?starttime=${starttime}&endtime=${endtime}&start=${mycounter}&limit=100

In first BeanShell Post Processor, I am incrementing only "mycounter" and I am expecting the while loop above that to execute till it goes false.

In the second BeanShell Processor, I am incrementing "startime" & "endtime" and I am epecting the while loop above it to execute till it goes false.

But, Observing that thinsg are not working as expected. Does my undertanding is correct. I see that the beanshell processors are not executing as per the WHile loops they fall under.
Any comments/Suggestions??

Answer (score 0):

Add For Loop controller to the plan.
Please refer [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9949415/how-to-set-counter-of-loop-inside-loop-correctly-inside-jmeter).

Comment: Can you explain more your more answer please ?