# Using Multiple JSON Files in Looped HTTP Request

Tags: json, jmeter

I have an HTTP Request within a Loop Controller. I also have multiple .json files that contain unique values based on unique constraints within the database to which I'm posting. Each file follows the naming convention Contract_*n*.json. (where n = 1, 2, 3, etc.)

The issue is this:

How do I get HTTP Request's Body to pick up a different file in each loop. I'm trying to figure out the best way to accomplish this. I have verified if I hard-code the full filename, it's successful on the first thread loop.

```
${__FileToString(C:/.../.../recallable payloads/${__eval(Contract_1)}.json,,)}
```

I've tried the following, and each fails:

```
${__FileToString(C:/.../.../recallable payloads/${__eval(Contract_(.+?))}.json,,)} 
${__FileToString(C:/.../.../recallable payloads/${__eval(Contract_)(.+?)}.json,,)} 
${__FileToString(C:/.../.../recallable payloads/${__eval(Contract_)}(.+?).json,,)}
```

The key is, I cannot put all of the records in a single file as that's not realistic for this situation. Each must be stored separately and picked up by the HTTP Request on each loop through the thread.

[HTTP Request and thread layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rxlBl.png)

[User Variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p9Yz4.png)

I just learned of the _StringFromFile function. Should I be using that?

I've tried using the following in the body.

```
 ${_StringFromFile(Contract_#'.'json,,1,2)}
```

This results in

```
 POST http://..../2002/crud/Contract
 POST data:
 **ERR**

 "RuntimeException",
 "cause": null,
 "message": "Unexpected character ('*' (code 42)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')\n
```

Yet I cannot find an * anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a jmeter loop controller you can add a **counter** config element. Have a look here
[how to set counter of loop inside loop correctly inside jmeter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9949415/how-to-set-counter-of-loop-inside-loop-correctly-inside-jmeter)

Also I would suggest putting the path in a user defined Variables config element to simplify things.. something like 
LocalDir 
${__BeanShell(import org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer; FileServer.getFileServer().getBaseDir(),)}

Then you can reference your configs like ${localDir}/Contract_${counter_index}.json

it would be helpful if you put a screen shot of the structure of your jmeter.

Comment: Dan, Thanks for the feedback.

I've added a screenshot of the HTTP Request and the User Defined Variables.

Comment: Dan, your answer steered me in the correct direct with successful results. After creating a Loop Counter, I was able to pass that into the Body:

     `${__FileToString(${Payload}/${__eval(Contract_${CtrtLoopCounter})}.json,,)} `

Thanks!